# Font Lato, bolded some Czech characters

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-fonts

I use the 'Lato' font on the website. The characters in Polish and English are displayed correctly, while some Czech characters are bolded. Below you can see that these 3 characters are bolded. What is the reason of this problem? Is this a font or browser problem?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900&amp;subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
      
        <style>


            body {
                font: normal 15px 'Lato';
                color: #000000;
                font-weight: 300;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="font-size: 30px;">Pověřenec pro ochranu osobních údajů</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Additonal printscreen](https://pasteboard.co/HxUqrtt.png)

Comment: Does Lato contain glyphs for these characters?

Comment: Hmm

I'm not sure, but on this page http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/, there is information that glyphs are supported.

But how does this relate to the Czech bolded characters?

Answer (score 1):

The glyphs are not available in Lato 1.0, which is also still used by Google Fonts.

Use Adobe Typekit, or download the font and include it on your website to fix the missing (bold) characters.

[Font can be found here](https://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the font size from the body css works fine:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,900,900i&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
      
        <style>


            body {
                font: normal 'Lato';
                color: #000000;
                font-weight: 300;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="font-size: 30px;">Pověřenec pro ochranu osobních údajů</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, there is still a problem. Look here

https://pasteboard.co/HxUKNdQ.png

Comment: In the screenshot, the offending characters are in a different font. So it's best to use another font that does include Czech.

Comment: What does it mean different font? This is the 'Lato' font all the time and it supports the Czech language because, as you can see, the Czech characters are correct, only they are bold. Unfortunately, changing the font is not possible. The problem is with "font-weight". When I remove "font-weight: 300" then all characters look identical, but they are too thick for me.

Comment: If you look carefully at the screenshot, the accented characters have serifs, while the plain characters do not. This means the browser takes these characters from a different font. The reason it does this is that Lato apparently does not include those characters at weight 300.